# Bash script for loop with find and many directories

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to do some work on a directory that contains many (100,000+) sub-directories. Is there a predefined limit to how many arguments you can pass to a for loop such as the following?

```
for dir in $(find . -type d)
do
  # My code
done
```

I'm worried the script will bork if the find command returns too many directories.

Comment: Out of interest, what filesystem are you using? I was under the impression that ext3, for example, was [limited to 32,000 directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Functionality)...

Comment: This is an ext4 filesystem. The directories are not all in one dir, rather they are organized by md5 in subdirs, e.g. 2/f/f80d0642f8ebfb07d23547adc107cb40

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't parse find output, and just use shell globbing - it's safer and built into the shell.  Shell built-ins like `for` are not subject to the same argument list length limit as external processes since no calls do `exec*` are made.

```
for dir in ./*/; do
    # ...
done
```

Comment: I actually omitted this because I didn't think it mattered, but I need to find only directories modified within a certain time frame, e.g. find . -type d -mtime 1. Is this possible with your syntax?

Comment: @Magnus Either use `find -exec` or check the time in the `for` loop.  Just don't try to parse the output of `find` or anything that simply prints file names.

Comment: Is there a source you can point to regarding why this would be a bad idea? I just tried a for..in $(find) with 40,000 directories and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Unix file names are allowed to contain any character except `\0` and `/`.  Things like that are basically binary blobs and can't be reliably parsed using things like command substitution - too many possible funny characters to mess up the parsing.  Try `mkdir test && cd test && mkdir 'one dir' && for dir in $(find . -type d); do printf '%s\n' "$dir"; done`.  You should see two directories, `one` and `dir`.

Comment: Ah, that's the point you were making. However, I control exactly the files in this directory, so I know they will not contain any "funny" characters. I guess my question was more "Will a bash for loop blow up if the find list becomes too large".

Comment: Ah I understand your question now.  There are two points: (1) shell built-ins like `for` are not limited by the normal argument list maximum length.  This applies whether you use command substitution or globbing.  (2) Command substitution is only safe if, as you say, you can completely control the output of `find`.  This includes limiting write access to the sub-tree of the file system in question to only trusted processes.  As you can see, such control is quite difficult to achieve, which is why I usually don't bother mentioning it.  However, if you can pull it off, go for it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm the only one using the machine and the only one creating files in this directory so there should be no worries.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `bash 4`, you can do something recursive like :

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in **/; do echo "$dir"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the answer you accepted -- you *will* run into memory issues if you use `$(find)`, even without an `exec` present.

Instead, write it as

```
find . -type d | while IFS= read -r dir
do
  # My code
done
```

(Note: this assumes that there is no directory name containing a newline character.)

Then you won't need the temporary memory to store the `find` output as you would with the command substitution.  This would also work if the `find` or other command never terminated, e.g.:

```
# will not work!
for line in $(yes) ; do echo "$line" ; done

# works
yes | while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "$line" ; done
```

Comment: So your solution runs the while loop for each line of output as soon as each output line from find appears, while mine pre-computes the entire thing and then runs the for loop. If I'm understanding things correctly. Surely the find will spit out dirs faster than the while loop can process them, so it would still need to buffer the output somewhere.

Comment: Yes, your first sentence is correct. For the second, no, the pipe will block and so `find` will also block while writing its output. In other words, `find` will simply wait if the loop can't keep up.

Comment: Wow, that is neat. I didn't even know pipes could block. You learn something new every day! I have just rewritten my script to do it your way and avoid any SNAFUs. I regret that I have but one accepted answer to give.

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate file names with a command substitution: this will break if the file names contain whitespace or `\[?*`.

With bash ≥4, ksh93 or zsh, you can avoid most uses of `find` that only use `-type d` or `-name …` predicates by using the `**` glob to match subdirectories at any depth. In bash, run `shopt -s globstar` first. In ksh, run `set -o globstar` first.

```
for dir in **/; do …; done
```

Portably, or in cases where you need more, use `find … -exec … +` or `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`. This approach has the added benefit of running `find` somewhat in parallel with the action on the files, though this only becomes true for huge directory trees (at least thousands of matching files). You can make `find` or `xargs` run a shell if you need to do more than run one command.

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'for x in "$@"; do echo "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

(That `_` is `$0` in the shell snippet, which we don't use.)